# Calculate RSSI Value

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I understand the calculation and method to obtain the distance (rough in me) from a BLE RSSI value. But my code continues to return 'nan'. Which means I'm dividing by zero at some point. Is my arithmetic/code correct?

```
float RSSIA = -40.0; // Reference RSSI value at 1 meter
float RSSIn = 1; // Path-loss exponent
//−(10n log10(RSSI) − A)

[peripheral readRSSI];

NSNumber *RSSI = peripheral.RSSI;
NSLog(@"%@|RSSI|%f|(m)", characteristic.service.peripheral.name ,-(10*RSSIn*(log10([RSSI doubleValue])-RSSIA)));
```

Comment: Did you check the `peripheral.RSSI` value before applying the `log10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RSSI` usually has a negative value. And the logarithm is defined only for numbers greater than 0. That's why you get `nan`.

You don't need to calculate the logarithm anyway. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:) states that `RSSI` is already in decibels:

```
The current received signal strength indicator (RSSI) of the peripheral, in decibels.
```

Also please note that `RSSI` property is deprecated. You should implement `CBPeripheralDelegate` and calculate the distance in `peripheral:didReadRSSI:error:` method. Although `RSSI` property is available, its value may be not up to date immediately after calling `[peripheral readRSSI]` - RSSI is being read asynchronously.